# How to show Validation error for input array?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

How can we show validation error message in **LARAVEL** where we have input array as:

`<input type="text" name="start_time[]" class="form-control start_time" value="" >`

because,
`start_time => 'required',`
does not work here

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi, I have tried the same initially but does not work, it works well in CodeIgniter.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama: Thanks for the link, but I did not get this, why is he including a blade file in between, I am new to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule has to be like this:

```
'start_time.*' => 'required'
```

I tested your situation with below details and everything worked fine.

view :

```
<form action="{{ route('test.store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="start_time[]" class="form-control start_time" value="" >

    <input type="text" name="start_time[]" class="form-control start_time" value="" >

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'start_time.*' => 'required'
    ]);
```

errors when form is blank :

```
The start_time.0 field is required.
The start_time.1 field is required.
```

Comment: @Saurabh if you show me a `dd` of your `request()->all()` that would be helpful

Comment: Right now I am submitting the blank form and I am expecting to get validation error messages.
But I am providing you `dd` of the field I need to show error validation message,
`"start_time" => array:2 [▶]`
  after expanding 'start_time',
`array:2 [▼
  0 => "12:10"
  1 => "04:25"
]`

Comment: @Saurabh Are you sure you're displaying errors correctly according to laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Comment: @Saurabh I tested your situation and there was no problem. you can see it in my updated answer. So maybe you should give me more details about your view and controller to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "start_time.*"  => "required",
]);
```

**Updated Answer**

```
$validator = $request->validate([
    "start_time"    => "required|array|min:10",
    "start_time.*"  => "required",
]);
```

Comment: @Saurabh: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: It is showing "The start time must have at least 10 items.". When I am changing
"start_time"    => "required|array|min:10",
 to 
"start_time"    => "required|array|min:1",
Then it is not showing any error.
Thanks for replying again.

Comment: Hello Sir, Please reply.